# realsense_ros_person process has died exit code -6 & Unsupported ROS image format: 16UC1

Tags: ros, launch, catkin, realsense

While entering the following command:

`roslaunch realsense_ros_person demo_person_tracking.launch`

for intel realsense camera in catkin workspace in ros kinetic environment,
I encountered the error:

```
[ERROR] [1529485355.268396466]: Unsupported ROS image format: 16UC1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unsupported ROS image format
[realsense_ros_person-3] process has died [pid 19040, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet standalone realsense_ros_person/TNodeletPt __name:=realsense_ros_person __log:=/home/janhvi/.ros/log/ce199cba-7467-11e8-8c5f-30e37a258f73/realsense_ros_person-3.log].
log file: /home/janhvi/.ros/log/ce199cba-7467-11e8-8c5f-30e37a258f73/realsense_ros_person-3*.log
```

Can anyone help regarding this issue?

Comment: It's Driver Problem What Realsense camera u have? what is Your linux kernel version? can you See Realsense Camera Image In `rqt_image_view`?

Comment: @MohammadAli I am using intel realsense R200 camera and yes i could see image in rqt_image_view. I solved this problem by reinstalling catkin workspace, may be some files got edited while working, but not sure what was the exact problem.